# Read specific json key from a list of file and saving it as a new file

Tags: python, json

I'm new to python and the task I am performing is to extract a specific key from a list of json files in a local directory. I wanted to extract the key/value 'data' and save it as a new file (with the existing filename) and repeat it for all other files.

```
{
    "link": "",
    "site": "",
    "date": "1593534296",
    "filename": "first",
    "size": 728,
    "time": "0",
    "language": "java",
    "data": "",
    "rule": [
        "matched"
    ]
}

import json
dirpath = r'\path'
output = []
files = os.listdir(dirpath)
for filename in files:
    with open(dirpath + '/' + filename , encoding="utf-8") as afile:
        output.append({'filename': filename, 'data': afile.read()})
        afile.close()
```

I started with opening files and reading them one by one. However I can only read the entire data. Can I get some help on how to only read the key 'data' and save it in a new file. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Simply use:

```
for filename in files:
    with open(dirpath + '/' + filename , encoding="utf-8") as afile:
        json_obj = json.load(afile)  # uses the json library to parse the file
        output.append({'filename': filename, 'data': json_obj['data']})  # gets only the value of the data attribute
        # you do not need to close the file here, the "with" statement does that for you
    # the file is already closed here
```

Comment: Thanks and how can I do the same for saving them into new files probably with the same filename as before?

Comment: If you want to save the output to a file, then after you close the file, open the file again using the //with open(filename, "w") as f:// statement and write the output to the file using f.write(output[-1]). Index -1 in python means "the last inserted member".

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to read the entire JSON file you could loop through it line by line, replacing the `"`, `:`, `,` characters and returning the line once you hit the key:

```py
    with open(YOUR_FILE, "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            a = line.replace("\"", "").replace(":", "").replace(",", "").split()
            if a[0] == "data":
                return a
```